# Proving that $UT=TU$ iff $U=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, which is a $T$-cyclic subspace of itself. How do I prove that $UT=TU$ iff $U=g(T)$ for some polynomial $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $V=\{\it 0\,\}$, then $U=T={\rm id}_V$ and the result
is clear. So we only consider $V\ne\{\it 0\,\}$ and let 
$V={\rm span}(\{v,T(v),T^2(v),\ldots\})$ for some
non-zero vector $v\in V$. If $UT=TU$,
assume that 
$$U(v)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kT^k(v)\quad\mbox{for some }n\in \mathbb{N}.$$
Define $g\in\mathbb{P}(F)$ by
$g(t)=a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_nt^n$, then $U(v)=g(T)(v)$.
However, we want to show that in general $U=g(T)$. Given 
$x\in V$, write $x=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^mb_kT^k(v)$ for some 
$m\in\mathbb{N}$ and scalars $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m\in F$. Since $U$
is linear and $UT=TU$ and
$g(T)T=Tg(T)$, we have
\begin{align}
U(x)
&=U\left(\sum_{k=0}^mb_kT^k(v)\right)
 =\sum_{k=0}^mb_kU(T^k(v))
 =\sum_{k=0}^mb_kT^k(U(v))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^mb_kT^k(g(T)(v))
 =\sum_{k=0}^mb_kg(T)(T^k(v))\\
&=g(T)\left(\sum_{k=0}^mb_kT^k(v)\right)
 =g(T)(x).
\end{align}
That is, $U=g(T)$, as desired. The converse is immediate because
$g(T)T=Tg(T)$ for all $g\in\mathbb{P}(F)$.

Comment: Actually, there's no need for the case analysis on whether $V = 0$ at all. The proof goes through just fine without it since the fact that $v$ is non-zero is also irrelevant and can be deleted.